# Error in vendor.bundle.js When Running Angular2 Application on IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, vendor

I have an angular2 application that works perfect on chrome.

But when I open this application with IE11, I see nothing.

in console, there is an error:

[image: console screenshot]

It seems like error in vendor.bundle.js.
In the pointed line at this file, there is calling to "eval" function with very long code.
I guess there are commands that are not supported in IE11.

What I want to do: to copy the code inside eval function, replace the calling eval with this code, then I will get the exact line where there is an error.

But vendor.bundle.js does not even appear in my app...

What is that file?
How can I change it?
Or maybe there is another solution to this problem?

Angular Info:

**Angular CLI: 1.6.4

  Node: 8.9.4

  OS: win32 x64

  Angular: 5.2.0**

**-----ADDING-----**

my polyfills.ts file:

```
// This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
// You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

// If you need to support the browsers/features below, uncomment the import
// and run `npm install import-name-here';
// Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html

// Needed for: IE9
// import 'classlist.js';

// Animations
// Needed for: All but Chrome and Firefox, Not supported in IE9
 import 'web-animations-js';

// Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes
// Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 import 'intl';

// NgClass on SVG elements
// Needed for: IE10, IE11
 import 'classlist.js';
```

Comment: That file is part of the compiled code you're deploying. It's hard to say what the problem is with so little information - give a [mcve] of your app configuration.

Comment: @jonrsharpe added angular version info. is it what you mean?

Comment: Is your application CLI based? Did you activate the polyfills?

Comment: @Osman Cea What do you mean?

Comment: If you built your application using the Angular CLI, there's a file called `polyfills.ts` with some pollyfills you have to uncomment and install in order for your app to work on IE, although I'm not sure if it's necessary for IE 11.

Comment: @Osman Cea I added my prolyfills.ts file. can you see it please?

Comment: I also have the same error even has enabled IE polyfill, do you solve it now? If yes, kindly let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I solved it by upgrading primeng version :(

Answer (score 0):

in `polyfills.ts`

You will filnd `/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/`

uncomment `imports` as:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: @nshuman Jaiswal I added my prolyfills.ts file to ask. please see it.